# sIFR double titles?

Tags: sifr, double

I used the latest [sIFR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Inman_Flash_Replacement) version, and for some reason it shows the title double. I've experienced this problem on 2 pages now.

I uploaded an example here:
http://www.romenov.com/fairflex/form.html
and for some reason, the problem does not occur on page.html

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly because you don't have the sIFR stylesheet included in the form.html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sifr.css" type="text/css">
```

:)

Comment: Happens to the best of us sometimes ;)